# Is the statistical significance of a regression meaningful if it has poor out of sample performance?

Tags: statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, validation

I want to determine the significance of a particular variable, among many confounders. If I fit a model on the training set and observe a small p value, should I discard the model because it extrapolates poorly on the test set (negative $R^2$ value), or should I keep it since I wasn't interested in predictions anyway?

Comment: It depends on your application and what your data looks like. How small is a "small" p-value? Are the extrapolated predictions *systematically* wrong, or do they nail down a trend through the middle of data that has a high variance?

Comment: p~1E-8. The question is does the particular variable, which is the time, predict the response variable or not. The explanatory variables are a mix of categorical and numerical. It's difficult to discern a trend purely using the particular variable because its effect is small; the other variables account for the bulk of the variance.

Comment: In that case I would say significance is still meaningful but unimportant. If you're trying to make predictions and the predictions are bad, then your model can't be good. It's possible that there is still a positive association between the predictor and the response; it's just too weak (relative to the noise in the data) to be of predictive value. Another possibility is that the underlying relationships in your in-sample and out-of-sample data are different. Also, did you plot the out-of-sample residuals? If they're symmetric you might still be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're interested in doing.

Statistical significance and out of sample performance are quite different criteria.

If your interest is in *prediction*, statistical significance isn't especially relevant.

On the other hand, if your interest is in whether some variable is more related to your response (after adjusting for the effect of other variables) than chance would allow (and that may a pretty limited set of circumstances), then out of sample predictive ability may not be especially important (that is, very weak effect may still matter).

What you should do *first* --- before you ever see data --- is carefully define your questions of interest and identify the particular criteria that *speak to those questions*. It's no use throwing this procedure and that procedure at your data and *then* saying 'wait, what am I doing this for anyway?'.

Figure out what you need your model to tell you. Then figure out how to do that.